# error for fzero "Function value at starting guess must be finite and real."

Tags: matlab

I display the x0 and make sure that it is real, but it also shows error. I don't know why? and I also plot the function, it surely shows a zero around x0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know that the error happens when the function value isn't real and finite. So how to avoid this error automatically. Otherwise I have to check every time which isn't so convenient for me to run many times.

Comment: What is `fun`? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and post [formatted code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) not images of code